# DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN

Tags: networking, network-manager

Ubuntu 16.04 now this morning delivers the above error.
Laptop running Windows 10 wired to same router works fine.
Ubuntu 13.10 from CD works fine.
What has happened? And how to fix.
Please appreciate I have very little Linux experience and desperately require a stable fix, which doesn't mean reverting to Windows.

Comment: In what situation do you get the message in your title? What happened before or after that?

Answer (score 1):

**For Ubuntu**

These errors indicate that there is some problem with DNS.

- check `cat /etc/resolv.conf` for your DNS settings.
- And add following name server in  `/etc/resolv.conf` for temporary or in `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head` for permanent

> ```
> nameserver 8.8.8.8
> nameserver 8.8.4.4
> ```

- To add these two name server address in `resolv.conf`

  - run command `sudo gedit /etc/resolv.conf`
  - Copy above two line of nameserver paste on last line of `resolv.conf`
  - Ctrl+S to save.
- Note: If you add name server only `/etc/resolv.conf` then when computer is restarted then `/etc/resolv.conf` is in previous stage.
  So, to store these nameservers permanently, use following method :

  - run command `sudo gedit /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head`
  - Copy above two lines of nameserver and paste on last line of `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head`
  - Ctrl+S to save.
- Re-connect internet connection

More Detail On https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Network_Debugging#DNS_Servers

**For Windows:**

- Add these DNS ip on network configuration
- Tutorial to add DNS in windows is here
  https://www.opennicproject.org/configure-your-dns/how-to-change-dns-servers-in-windows-7/
- Re-connect internet connection

Answer (score -1):

You can try below solution to fix [DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN](https://trinitytuts.com/tips/resolve-dns_probe_finished_nxdomain-in-linux/) issues.

1. Release and Renew IP Address
2. Restart DNS Client Service
3. Change DNS Servers
4. Reset Your Browser
5. Disable VPN and Antivirus Temporarily

[DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN](https://trinitytuts.com/tips/resolve-dns_probe_finished_nxdomain-in-linux/) Fix